# How to get class name using jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have an element like this:

```
<div id="dv" class="red green blue">Something Here !!</div>
```

I used this:

```
alert($('#dv').attr('class'));
```

But it gives me all three at the same time, I need individually probably stored in an array.

How do I get each of those class names using jquery? Should be simple, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var classNames = $('#dv').attr('class').split(' ');
```

if you just need to know if an element owns a class you might want to use

```
if( $('#dv').is('.green') ){
    alert('its green!');
}
```

or

```
if( $('#dv').hasClass('green') ){
    alert('its green!');
}
```

which is a derived function. Keep attention to the different notation

".className" and just "className"

Answer (score 8):

There are a few ways depending on your objective (do you *actually* need an array, might be a quicker method!).

To get an array of the classes use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`.split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp):

```
$('#dv').attr('class').split(' ') == ['red', 'green', 'blue']
```

To get the literal string use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#dv').attr('class') == 'red green blue'
```

To check for a class use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
$('#dv').hasClass('red') == true
```

Comment: +1 for `hasClass`, which is more likely what the OP needs if he's trying to split the class attribute into an array.

Comment: @Andy E's head - Considering the ID is "dv", and the classes are "red green blue" I wonder if the class attribute is being used used as storage for RGB values?? Either way, +1 since Nick met his normal standard by covering the bases.

Answer (score 3):

The class is an attribute so you can do `var classname=$("#dv").attr("class")`
then you can split it into an array with `var array=classname.split(" ");`

Answer (score 2):

with `attr()` you can set or retrieve any attribute you want. If you have more then one class you can split the string that attr gives you back with `split("separator")`. Split gives you back an array. 
`$.each(array, function(i, data){})` allows you to do something for each value in a array. If you put that together this is the result:

```
$.each( $("#dv").attr("class").split(" "), function(i, data) {
    alert(data)
})
```

And here a demo with your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cq5JD/

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
alert($('#dv').attr('class'));
```